# Coloring nodes in sequence in a graph

Tags: graph, data-visualization

I have a graph (nodes-edges) , in which I want to highlight certain nodes. Additionally, I want the highlight to define a sequence i.e. I want to viewer to know that a particular node comes 'before' another node. The easy way out here, I can think of, is to color the nodes to be high-lit with shades of the same color, varying the shade from light to dark to represent the sequence (a darker node occurs in the sequence after a node with a loghter shade). My problem here is the number of nodes I wish to highlight is typically 500, and I dont think having 500 shades of the same would make the the sequence very discernible . Of course, the viewer would still get an approx idea, but is there a better visualization technique I can use?

Thanks!